# Is it possible to use AndroidHttpClient with PersistentCookieStore?

Tags: android, apache, android-networking, apache-commons-httpclient, androidhttpclient

I would like to use AndroidHttpClient instead of DefaultHttpClient.
In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) is say:

> This client processes cookies but does not retain them by default. To retain cookies, simply add a cookie store to the HttpContext:

```
context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

Where do I get this context from???
Should I get it from the AndroidHttpClient or should I create it first and then pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(...);
HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
ctx.setAttribute(...);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(...);

client.execute(get, ctx);
```